# Get element contents from element C#

Tags: c#, xml

[so here is the code i am using to get the other elements from my xml.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBCdf.png)

I have a data grid view that displays a lot of other elements but whenever I try to get 'Address1' etc it throws up an error. But I can call 'Address' and it puts all the elements of address into the one cell in my datagridview.

Can someone help me get 'Address1' and 'Address2' etc by themselves? I am stuck on this for a while now.
So am trying to get the details from 'Address1 & Address2'

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: What about an XML parser?

Comment: Deserialize into an Address object and get property Address.Address1

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement to parse your XML. ie:

```
void Main()
{
     string s = @"<address>
     <address1>Address 1</address1>
     <address2>Address 2</address2>
     <address3>Address 3</address3>
     <address4>Address 4</address4>
     <postcode>1234</postcode>
     <country>MyCountry</country>
     </address>";

    var data = from r in XElement.Parse(s).DescendantsAndSelf("address")
               select new {
                Address1 = (string)r.Element("address1"),
                Address2 = (string)r.Element("address2"),
                Address3 = (string)r.Element("address3"),
                Address4 = (string)r.Element("address4"),
                Postcode = (string)r.Element("postcode"),
                Country = (string)r.Element("country")
               };
 foreach(var d in data)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"Address line1:{d.Address1}, Postcode:{d.Postcode}");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with XDocument and then easily git the values of any node or its childs
see the following example:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("filePath, xml as a stream, xml reader or text reader" );
var elems = fileDataXDoc.Descendants("Address").Elements();
```

the above part of code will return all sub address nodes as `IEnumerable<XElements>`
then you can work with it

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score"